# Is there a mathematical relation between the volume of a speaker diaphragm and the intensity of sound it produces?

Tags: acoustics

I am trying to find out how speaker cones of different diaphragm volumes will produce a certain intensity of sound. Is there a relation that could be used after the volume of the cone has been found?

Comment: This will also depend on the force that the speaker coil can impart to the cone as a function of the current, and then on the frequency dependence of all the dynamics. So it is a complicated question. I can imagine that there might be a semi-empirical *limit* to the sound intensity produced, *i.e.* the maximum possible intensity of an optimally designed speaker as a function of size. You *may* have better luck with an answer on Electrical Engineering or Engineering stack exchange - not saying it doesn't belong here, but try there if no joy here.

Comment: Can you define "intensity" ?  If not, you're a bit behind the knowledge curve to be able to analyze this situation.  The volume is only part of the deal: there's the excursion (throw), the coil power, the impedance matching of the acoustic wave to the room air, and more.

Comment: What do you mean by the volume of a diaphragm? Do you mean the volume of air it displaces when it moves? That would not be a property of the diaphragm but would also depend on the amplitude of the motion. In a simplified model of a monopole source, the radiated power is expected to be proportional to $x^2A\omega^2$, where $x$ is the amplitude of the motion, $A$ is the cross-sectional area, and $\omega$ is the frequency. In reality, the speaker cone couples acoustically to the speaker in a complicated way, and the driver's response at high frequencies could depend, e.g., on its inertia.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my back-of-the-envope calculation. The volume of the speaker and the intensity of the sound are proportional.

The intensity $I$ of the sound is essentially the amount of energy that is transferred to the air in a unit of time. This, in turn, is proportional to the surface area $a$ of the diaphragm (twice the area, twice the column of air that is displaced). Since the area and volume $v$ are related by $a \propto v^{2/3}$, one would imagine that $I\propto v^{2/3}$. Remember that the intensity of the sound is not the same as the loudness $l$ of the sound (in $\mathrm{dB}$, say) that you would perceive. The latter is a logarithm of the intensity. The relation between the volume and the loudness would be $l\propto \log{v^{2/3}}.$ The base of the logarithm is irrelevant for proportionality.

One more thing to consider is the amplitude $A$ of the oscillating motion of the diaphragm. If the speaker is larger, this amplitude will be proportionally larger. (This does require an equal increase in the potential or Voltage applied to the speaker.) The amplitude is proportional to the intensity of the produced sound. Furthermore, given that the speakers of different sizes have the same shape, $A\propto v^{1/3}$. Taking both this and the surface area in account, we find that $I\propto Aa\propto v$ and consequently $l\propto \log v$.

The intensity of the sound and the volume of the speaker are proportional, which is to say $$v=\frac{I}{\rho} ,$$ for some $\rho$. This constant of proportionality has the SI-unit $\mathrm{Wm^{-1/3}}$, so it is a power density.

Comment: Intensity is not generally proportional to $A a$ but rather something like $A^2 a$, the square of the amplitude. Similarly, the amplitude may not scale linearly with a speaker-size-length, but at the same force you'd expect that it has twice the mass and accelerates half as much, so if the drags acting on it are linear then $A \propto v^{-1/3}$ or so. Combining both such effects, you probably get that the overall volume of the cone has nowhere near the effect that the shape of the cone or the electronics that drive it would matter.